# HTML display error - intermittent line break/carriage return

Tags: php, html, css

I'm coding in HTML/PHP/CSS using CodeIgniter framework.

I have a weird display error going on that's driving me nuts!

Most of the time, the area in question displays absolutely fine.....however, once in say 5 reloads the page will not display correctly.  Even to the point where you just hit refresh and display EXACTLY the same page and content, it'll cause the error.

It's a simple DIV (here's the css)...

```
.shell {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.shell-content1 {
    padding: 0 20 20 20;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/top-content-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    min-height:68%;
}
.shell-content1 h1 {
    color: 2e3192;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.shell-content1 h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.content-header {
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #5a7f97;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;

    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    height:33px;
    line-height:33px;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/content-header-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

...and here is the html code...

```
<body>
    <div class="shell-content1">
        <div class="shell">
            <div class="breadcrumb">
                <div class="breadcrumb-left">
                    >> <a href="homepage">Home</a> >> <a href="/myaccount">My Account</a> >> Edit Course 
                </div><!--BREADCRUMB-LEFT-->
                <div class="breadcrumb-right">
                    <?php include(APPPATH.'views/templates/breadcrumb-loggedin.php');?>
                </div>
            </div><!--BREADCRUMB-->

            <div class="content-header">Edit Course : <?php echo $course->course_title;?></div>
            <div class="content-text">
```

I've cut down the code to only show the pertinent sections.

The part that's causing the error is the DIV = content-header.  When it errors, the last word of the line (generated via the $course->course_title variable) ends up in a new line, and overlaying other content on the page beneath it.  It's doesn't displace the subsequent text....it's overlayed like it's got an absolute position.

I can't see why this is happening.....does anyone else have any suggestions??

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: can u provide fiddle link?

Comment: I just tried....had to cut a lot out due to CodeIgniter/database driven content....and it works every single refresh.  So I'm guessing it must be something else that's effecting this section of code.  I'll have to dig deeper I think.

Comment: Off topic, but you have errors in your CSS: hex colors should start with #; and min-height only works if the height of the parent element is specified.